# ¿Cómo puedo acceder a un objeto que me esta devolviendo el método?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

¿Cómo puedo acceder a un método que me esta devolviendo un `object` pero ese resultado lo estoy almacenando en una variable de tipo `object`? Ejemplo:

Método que consume una api y retorna el response:

```
static async Task<Object> GetPersonAsync(string path)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await HttpService.GenerateClient().GetAsync(path);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Persona persona = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Persona>();
        }

        return persona;
    }
```

Controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View(model);

        // Mi codigo
        //
        //

            object per = await GetPersonAsync("rutahacialaapi");

        ...

    }
```

Modelo:

```
public class Persona
{
    public int prop { get; set; }
}
```

Estaba tratando de ingresar a las propiedades de ese objeto así `per.` pero no me aparecen las propiedades que tiene ese modelo...

**ACTUALIZADO**

Si examino lo que me trae `object per` me aparece esto `per = {NombreProyecto.Models.Persona}`, si abro eso me aparece esto `prop = 00000` es esa la propiedad a la que no puedo acceder.

**PRUEBAS**

Trate de acceder a el asi.

```
Persona persona = await GetPersonAsync("rutahacialaapi");
```

Pero me indica el siguiente error.

> No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo object en NombreProyecto.Models.Persona. Ya existe una conversión explicita (Compruebe si le falta una conversión)

¿Quién me puede ayudar?

Comment: Quieres acceder a la propiedad `prop` del `object` `per`?, porque no lo conviertes automaticamente a Persona? `Persona per = await ...`

Comment: @Andrespengineer Exacto, el `await GetPersonAsync("rutahacialaapi")` me devuelve un objeto del tipo `Persona` el cual lo almaceno en un objeto `per` pero para acceder a las propiedades no eh podido.

Comment: Pero, por que lo almacenas en un objeto tipo `object` y no en uno tipo `Persona`?, mira la respuesta que te hicieron.

Comment: @Andrespengineer Si lo había intentado pero me da un error, en la respuesta de mas abajo comente el error que me arroja.

Comment: te recomiendo que leas la documentación detenidamente, hay varios conceptos enredados aquí...

Comment: @fredyfx ¿Por que hay varios conceptos enredados?

Comment: Porque estás aprendiendo (según percibo). Tienes un Task Object que retorna un tipo Persona... Hay un login con cero parámetros que verificas si el modelo es válido... Quieres obtener una clase en base a un objeto sin una conversión... Definitivamente te recomiendo llevar unas clases de cómo construir WebAPIs en https://mva.microsoft.com son gratuitas y de alto nivel. También lleva unas clases de ASP.net MVC, por si deseas material en español este video te será de ayuda, hice lo posible para dejar claro los conceptos: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY Saludos :D

Comment: @fredyfx Los parámetros del Login no los escribí por que no son de importancia para la pregunta que hice. Que debería retornar entonces el Task? Y el tema de la conversión es a lo que va mi pregunta...

Comment: Puedes revisar el Update de mi respuesta, tu metodo deberia retornar null si no devuelve un resultado success. Ya en el metodo que recibe el resultado evaluas si persona es diferente de null para ejecutar las operaciones con dicho objeto. Buena suerte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es porque se debe hacer una conversión **explicita** al objeto resultante y no de manera **implícita**:

```
Persona persona = (await GetPersonAsync("rutahacialaapi")) as Persona;
```

Se utiliza el keyword `as` en vez de hacer un cast directo. Si lo intentas hacer así:

```
Persona persona = (Persona) await GetPersonAsync("rutahacialaapi");
```

Puede ser que el objeto resultante no pueda convertirse explicitamente a `Persona` y te lanzará la excepción `InvalidCastException`. Sin embargo al hacerlo con `as`, captura la excepción y devuelve `null` en caso de que no se pueda hacer el cast.

**Solución recomendada:** En vez de devolver `Task<Object>` , deberias cambiarlo a `Task<Persona>`. Si devuelves `Persona` directamente entonces no hace falta la conversión explícita de object a `Persona` y no te daría el error que dices. Y como caso de ruptura, deberías poner un else en tu `Task` que devuelva null si response is not successful.

Tu metodo que consume el API deberia reflejarse asi:

```
static async Task<Persona> GetPersonAsync(string path){
        Persona persona = null;
        HttpResponseMessage response = await HttpService.GenerateClient().GetAsync(path);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            persona = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Persona>();

        return persona;
    }
```

Comment: Me sirvió demacrado, muchas gracias !.

Answer (score 0):

no te muestra la propiedad porque lo estas recibiendo como un object, deberías recibirlo como Persona, asi:

```
Persona per = await GetPersonAsync("rutahacialaapi");
```

Comment: Si habia intentado hacerlo de esa manera pero me da un error... * "No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo `object` en `NombreProyecto.Models.Persona`. Ya existe una conversión explicita (Compruebe si le falta una conversión) "*

Comment: intenta de esa manera `Task<Persona> GetPersonAsync`